# If URL contains string then run jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website id like to run a jQuery function if my url contains the word 'test'

All im trying to do is if my url contains the 'rest' string then add a margin to an element on the page?

Ive added a jSfiddle to try and show what Ive done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    // How can I check to see if my url contains the word 'TEST' then run the below function?
    $('.block-widget').css('margin-top, 252px')     
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `window.location` to get the current location url..

Based on the condition you can then apply the margin top property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
     if(pathname.indexOf('text') > -1){
        $('.block-widget').css('margin-top, 252px');
     }     
});
```

Comment: I don't think that the path is the only part where `test` could/should appear

Comment: @Bergi we will assume the OP knows enough about programming to inspect `window.location` themselves & find the solution. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
   if (document.url.match(/test/g)){
     $('.block-widget').css('margin-top, 252px')     
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link that contains details that you need to know about URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('rest') >= 0) {
      $('.block-widget').css('margin-top, 252px')     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the path name:

`var pathname = window.location.pathname;`

Then check if it contains "TEST".

`if (pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("test") >= 0)`

Comment: You're using toLowerCase() so you should check for 'test'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    var patt=/test/g;
    if(patt.test(window.location.pathname)){
    $('.block-widget').css('margin-top, 252px')  
  }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**name*='keyword'** selector is true option.

```
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">

<script>
$( "input[name*='man']" ).val( "has man in it!" );
</script>
```

Resource: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/