# check if current URL has this $string in jquery

Tags: jquery

need some help building the logic syntax for this JQUERY condition.

if the current url window includes a specific `$string` (index.php) then i want to add a value to a specific `<li>` class. as seen below.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>index</li>
</ul>
```

this is the target element
`('.nav li:nth-child(2) ').addClass("selected")`.

this is my jquery. im not quite sure how to code the correct syntax for my logic.

```
 $j(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var string = 'index.php';

    if //current url has $string ('index.php') {
     $j( ".nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
    });
 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [If URL contains string then run jQuery function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534245/if-url-contains-string-then-run-jquery-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var string = 'index.php';
if(url.indexOf(string) !== -1) {
   $j( ".nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
}
```

Comment: thank you. but would you mind explain to me this part `(url.indexOf(string) !== -1)` why `!== -1`?

Comment: @user1933824 Sure. `String.indexOf` returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified value or `-1` if the value is not found. So `> -1` and `>= 0` would be also correct to check if the url has some string value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

This allows you to search for a specific string (case sensitive)

Comment: This is not what the op is looking for, though. This could work on `[<element> {search_term} </element>].contains({search_term});` NOTE: This is not valid code, also the `[]` notation is to indicate a jQuery object. He needs to search the _url_ for the string, not inside an element (or a collection of them).

Answer (score 0):

This would be better done on the server-side, since the `window.location.path` won't contain `index.php` in redirect and default page scenarios.

Just echo a `<script>` tag or a global setting variable from `index.php`:

```
<!-- in index.php -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     Settings.isIndex = true;
</script>
```

And in script.js:

```
var Settings = { isIndex: false };

$j(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var string = 'index.php';

    if (Settings.isIndex) {
      $j( ".nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe `index.php` was just an example. What if he can't control the server-side? Also, wouldn't it be easier to simpler to just `echo` the additional class into the element's `class` attribute directly from the server-side, then?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var your_string = 'index.php';

if(url.contains(your_string) === true ) {
    $j( ".nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
}
```

or

```
if(url.indexOf(your_string) !== -1) {
    $j( ".nav li:nth-child(2)" ).addClass( "active" );
}
```